# Web Services that Converts Lat Lon to Zip Code

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, web-service, geoprocessing-service, zip-codes

Does anyone know of a Web Services  that can convert a Lat Lon to a Zip Code?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Thank you for taking the new user [tour].  A good question should show some degree of self-research.  What did your research turn up?  Did those tools not work?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options:

[Latitude / Longitude to ZIP + 4](http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/latlngzip4.asp?), allows you to input the lat, long and receive a Zip code in return.

You could also use this to input the values and run the search yourself

[All US zip codes with their corresponding latitude and longitude coordinates. Comma delimited for your database](https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666)

Comment: Great, thank you. I suppose that I could truncate my lat lon to the 3rd decimal the look for the corresponding the the census dat to get a close approximation of zip code.